# React-Redux Connecting a function base component to dispatch to props

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying form filled data to props.
I KNOW REACT-REDUX but not getting how to connect function based component

this is my snippet:

```
import React from 'react';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

// import { connect } from "react-redux";

export default function TextFields(props) {

  const [values, setValues] = React.useState({
    ssn: '',
    phone: '',
    email: '',
    multiline: 'Controlled',
  });

  const handleChange = name => event => {
    setValues({ ...values, [name]: event.target.value });
  };

  const onSubmit = () => {
    const data = {
      ssn: values.ssn,
      email: values.email
    }
    console.log(data)
    props.dispatch({type: 'SUBMIT', data})
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>

      <form noValidate autoComplete="off">
       <TextField
        id=""
        label="SSN"
        value={values.ssn}
        onChange={handleChange('ssn')}
        type="number"
        name='ssn'
      />
       <TextField
        id=""
        label="Email"
        value={values.email}
        onChange={handleChange('email')}
        type="email"
        name='email'
      />

      <Button
        onClick={() => onSubmit()}
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        size="small"
      >
        Save
      </Button>
    </form>
    </React.Fragment>

  );
}
```

I want when user fill the form and click on submit button, it should dispatch the data to props.

I tried with like `props.dispatch({type: 'SUBMIT', data})`

but it through a error that dispatch is not a function.
Can anyone help me to connect redux to dispatch the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to Stack Overflow.

First, you need to make a map to get your dispatch actions. You can do this by creating a function/arrow function that returns the props, like this (if you're using a function to perform the action, make sure to IMPORT the function as well):

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
 return {
 someAction: () => dispatch(actionFunction())
}
}
```

You can also dispatch directly the type of action:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
 return {
 someAction: () => dispatch({type: "ACTION_TYPE"})
}
}
```

and then connect it to the function:

```
export default connect ({}, mapDispatchToProps) (yourComponent);
```

You can see more in the doc below:
https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch

Comment: I know it but  how can i do it in my current component?